# How to make a button modify a label each time it is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically what I am trying to do is make a simple point counter like in dungeons and dragons or in  Fallout 4 at the beginning.

```
from tkinter import *

points = 21
global Strength
global dexterity
global intelligence
def Plus():
print("hi")
label = Label(root, text = points)
label.grid()

strengthlb = Label(root, text = "Strength")
strengthlb.grid()


strplusbtn = Button(root, text = "+", command = points -1)
strplusbtn.grid()

label.config(text = points)

strengthcoutnerlb = Label(root, text = 0)
```

My goal is when I click the button called `strplusbtn` I add 1 to the `strengthcounterlb` and subtract 1 from the label called `label` and the variable called `points`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can configure a button's `command` option so that it calls the
   referred method when pressed.
2. You can configure a label's text by configuring its `text` option.
3. A method can do arithmetic operations on variables within reach of
   its scope, such as globals.

In the below code `plus` button is configured to call `increase_str` method when pressed. That method modifies global variables(`points`, `strength`, `tot_atr`, `str_atr`) and labels' text options.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def increase_str():
    global points, strength
    strength += 1
    points -= 1
    tot_atr['text'] = "Total Points: {}".format(points)
    str_atr['text'] = "Strength: {}".format(strength)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    points = 10
    strength = 5
    tot_atr = tk.Label(root, text="Total Points: {}".format(points))
    str_atr = tk.Label(root, text="Strength: {}".format(strength))
    plus = tk.Button(root, text="+", command=increase_str)

    tot_atr.pack()
    str_atr.pack(side='left')
    plus.pack(side='left')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: code-only answers are discouraged. This answer would be much better if you explained what you changed to make it work, so that the OP or anyone else doesn't have to compare your code line-by-line to the original.

Comment: i will fix it! don't you worry

Comment: what is the purpose of the if statement and the tot_atr variables? @Nae sorry if this  is not a new thing i am recently new to python.

Comment: oh wait i know what those are they are the labels being created (duh) sorry